# How can I push URLs of returned items from Firebase Cloud Storage into an array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

**Goal:**
The goal is to return images stored in a Firebase Storage bucket using `listAll()` then get their URLs using `getDownloadURL()` and push each URL to an array that would be used to display the images in a gallery.

**Problem:**
I succeeded in returning the URLs but I get this error: `TypeError: "_this is undefined"` when I try to push them to an empty array.

**What I did:**
I tried several approaches over the last 3 days and this was the best I could come up with:

*Declaring an empty array:*
`export class imgService {`
`public images = []`
*The method:*

```
//creating a reference
var itemsRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('images/');
// listing the images
itemsRef.listAll().then(function (result) {
    result.items.forEach(function (itemRef) {
        // getting the URLs of the images
        itemRef.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
            console.log('URL:' + downloadURL);
            // pushing URLs to the empty images array
            this.images.push(downloadURL); //PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
        }).catch(function (error) {
            //Handling error here
        });
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    //Handling error here
});
```

I'm new to all of this, just trying to learn web technologies, so please go easy on me.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem lies in the understanding of how 'this' works in js.
As stated on the [mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) there are two ways of solving the problem you are facing.

First to identify the problem:

> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding). It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called.

In the current context you lose the reference to the 'this' you want by defining a regular function to handle `listAll().then` and `result.items.forEach`.

Then look at the possible solutions:

> ES5 introduced the bind() method to set the value of a function's this
>   regardless of how it's called, and ES2015 introduced arrow functions
>   which don't provide their own this binding (it retains the this value
>   of the enclosing lexical context).

So we can explicity [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to the 'this' you mean or just pass it all the down by using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). My personal preference goes to the arrow notation in this case so the following code should work.

Hopes this solves your problem and helps you understand what the underlying problem is.

```
//creating a reference
var itemsRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('images/');
// listing the images
itemsRef.listAll().then((result) => {
    result.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
        // getting the URLs of the images
        itemRef.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
            console.log('URL:' + downloadURL);
            // pushing URLs to the empty images array
            this.images.push(downloadURL); //PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
        }).catch(function (error) {
            //Handling error here
        });
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    //Handling error here
});
```